# Listen for keystrokes and execute code when a word is typed

Tags: java, keyboard, jframe

I am just looking for some direction of what type of keywords' I should be using when trying to find a solution to my problem as I am not finding any results the way I am typing it.
Basically, I want my program to monitor the last 5 keyboard keys pressed constantly whilst I'm running the jframes etc.

As it remembers the last 5, I want it to scan them until they match the pre-set passcode if you will. should the 5 characters match I want a backdoor/hidden developers jframe to open. I am saying 5 characters to keep it simple. Once I understand I will probably increase to make it more secure. And as this is going to be a local program I am just going to hardcode the pre-set password into the program. Any one using the software will not be 'clued up' on java enough to exploit this.

Any help would be appreciated,

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is completely answering your question.

I used javascript to create a function that will write down whatever was typed every 5 characters:

```
<textarea id="input" onkeyup="check()" maxlength="5"></textarea>
<p id="p"></p>
<script>
  var n = 0;

  function check() {
    if (event.keyCode >= 48 && event.keyCode <= 57 || event.keyCode >= 65 && event.keyCode <= 90) {
      n += 1;
      if (n == 5 || document.getElementById('input').value.length == 5) {
        document.getElementById('p').innerText = document.getElementById('input').value;
        n = 0;
        document.getElementById('input').value = "";
      }
    }
    if (event.key == "Backspace" || event.key == "Delete") {
        n -= 1;
    }
  }

</script>
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pvmutfu3/) showing it.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to implement your own key listener and "attach" it to the main frame/window. As the keys are typed you want to keep track of them. A FIFO (first in, first out) queue sounds like what you want. Each time you type a key, pop once and then add the key typed to the queue. A linked list would probably suffice.

It will be necessary to check that queue regularly to see if you should launch the the hidden developer controls. If you put the queue in your key listener then you might want to use a variable in the main program and give your key listener a reference to it so the two classes can communicate that way. Otherwise you could keep the queue in the main class, but the key listener will need a reference to *that* so it can modify the queue. Regardless the code to 
launch the developer controls will need to get called by somebody and I would recommend keeping that code in the main class as it doesn't really pertain to handling key events.

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html
- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyListener.html
- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html

P.S.
Using a linked list is helpful here because the default Java one implements the queue and list interfaces and so it's possible to iterate over the contents as well as see how many elements are in it.

It might be easier to just:
+ put stuff in list/queue
+ check if it has 5 characters
+ copy those 5 characters to a shared string
+ change a shared boolean to true
+ clear the queue
^ the last 3 steps should only occur if that shared boolean is false (i.e. initial or the main program hasn't checked it yet), otherwise you just want to maintain the list/queue at length 5 or less. you could let it grow unchecked, but that just uses unnecessary memory imho.